# MySQL find reconds that contain a question mark

Tags: mysql

I'm importing data from a csv file and I can see that the first record contains a question mark as the first character for the first record imported.
e.g. 1,?A product,120mls

I'm reading up on character encoding and working on that as the database has a need for COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci on some of the tables, but even setting the character encoding to uft8 for this specific table still results in the first record import with the question mark.

Editing the question to show the results based on the comments.
The CSV file does not contain a space or any character that I can see.

I dropped the table, recreated it and removed the first record from the CSV file as a test before importing and the result is still the same
Is there a way to find records that contain the question mark LIKE'?%' or %?% returns an empty set

Editing the question to show the results based on the comments. I dropped and recreated the table and removed the first row from the CSV file as a test but the result is the same
Note the xxxx are just me masking the data and not what is contained in the CSV or the table.

```
+--------+---------------------------------------------+-------+
| drugid | dname                                       | dsize |
+--------+---------------------------------------------+-------+
|      1 | ?A S xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   | 30LOZ |  
|      2 | A S  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx            | 50ML  |
|      3 | A V  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                        | 50ML  |
|      4 | A V  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                       | 100ML |
|      5 | A V  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                  | 50ML  |
+--------+---------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Update I've opened the CSV file (created using Excel) looking at it with Windex and I see the following at the start ï»¿A

Comment: Hmmm...are you sure that those question marks represent actual data, or is it possible that they are simply markers being used by MySQL to indicate that the actual data cannot be rendered properly??

Comment: If this only happens at the beginning of the first line, check if Unicode BOM (byte-order mark) is the cause.

Comment: Is the first character a question mark or a character the program you use to display the data cannot display?

Comment: @Tomm as mentioned in my question %?% returns an empty set

Comment: Thanks for the hints I wouldn't have thought of BOM. Sorted by changing the encoding of the file before importing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character is not a question mark, it's the so called [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or short called BOM only displayed as a question mark (there is no character for displaying a BOM). Remove it before parsing/handling the CSV file and you are fine.